# Why can't my User Form Input Fields pull back decimal places?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to pull back a handful of metrics into a User Form from deals that have been previously killed. Specifically my LTV field keeps pulling back the percentage without the decimal place. I've shortened the inputs below for reference.

```
Private Sub ComboBoxDealName_Change()

            InputMargin.Value = DeadTbl.Range.Cells(i + 1, [Dead_Margin].Column)
            InputLTV.Value = DeadTbl.Range.Cells(i + 1, [Dead_LTV].Column) * 100
            InputFee.Value = DeadTbl.Range.Cells(i + 1, [Dead_Fee].Column)

End Sub
```

The formatting for my input field looks like this...

```
Private Sub InputLTV_Change()
    InputLTV.Text = Format(InputLTV, "%#.#")
    InputLTV.TextAlign = fmTextAlignRight
End Sub
```

Comment: is `,` supposed to be the decimal separator?

Comment: Sorry @ScottCraner I added the wrong input field. I've edited the actual.

Comment: Don't multiply it by `100` but using the `%` it will automatically do the conversion.